# cyrillic URLs in apache access log

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, utf-8

My website is configured to include cyrilic urls for SEO reasons, using some RewriteRules.

It wall works very well and the link look like this

```
http://site.com/категория/новина.html
```

now, the issue problem I have is that when apache logs the request in the access.log it saves it in this format:

```
http://site.com/%D0%94%D0%B0/%D0%BC%D1%D0.html
```

How can I configure apache to save to access.log the correct cyrilic url ?

Answer (score 3):

That's because that *is* the URL that is being sent.  It may appear in Cyrillic in your browser's address bar, but when it gets sent to the server, it automatically gets URL encoded by your browser.  There's already [a post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888591/why-apache-htaccess-rewrites-non-latin-character-url-to-urlencoded-how-to-solve) about this same thing (see the accepted answer).